# Which path can/cannot be used Used to proof that the limit of a two-variable function doesn't exist.

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

This may be similar to an existing question, but is different.

I have learnt in my multivariable calculus class that to proof that the limit of a two-variable function doesn't exist, let us take it to be:
$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$$

What can be done is to take two paths, let us say $y=0$ and $y=x$ and show that it will take two different value of limits.

If we use the path $y=0$, the limit of the function would be
$$\lim_{(x,0)\to (0,0)} f(x,0) = \frac{0}{x^2+0^2}$$
$$=0$$

And if we use the path $x=y$, then,
$$\lim_{(x,x)\to (0,0)} f(x,x) = \frac{x^2}{x^2+x^2}$$
$$\lim_{(x,x)\to (0,0)} f(x,x) = \frac{x^2}{2x^2}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}$$

And since taking different paths leads to different values of limit, the limit does not exist.

My question is, which paths can we use or not use when proofing that a limit does not exist.

My guess is that any path that contains the point $(0,0)$ can be used, s this correct? So would that mean a line such as $y = x^3 + x^2 +2x$ be a valid path?

Or should the path be in a way "contained" in the plane of the two-variable function?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the existing question you believe it might be similar to?

Comment: Your proof that the limit doesn't exist is perfect. You can use any two paths to show that the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: @JohnDouma there might be a mistake in the calculation of the first path limit, I believe they used the path $y=0$ instead of $x=0$ as they stated, it might be a typo but could represent a deeper misunderstanding

Comment: @Carlyle I believe that is a typo. You can see that by what variable gets the zero. But $x=0$ would have also worked.

Comment: @SohamSaha Yes sure, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2132967/choosing-two-distinct-paths-for-calculating-the-limits-of-two-variable-functions

Comment: @Carlyle Ah yes that is a typo on my side, fixed. Thanks for the reminder

Comment: @JohnDouma So does that mean that the path of the function does not have to be "contained" in the surface resulted (since f(x,y) would be z, it can be represented as a 3d surface)?

Comment: @Willow I don't understand your question. It is important to understand why this technique works. If the limit did exist, then for any $\epsilon\gt 0$ we would be able to find a $\delta\gt 0$ such that every $(x,y)$ that lies within $\delta$ of the origin would be such that $f(x,y)$ was within $\epsilon$ of the limit. Since you have demonstrated that all $(x,y)$ such that $y=x$ are such that $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}$ and all $(x,y)$ such that $y=0$ have $f(x,y)=0$, there can be no limit because there are always points within any ball of radius $\delta$ that are at least $\frac{1}{2}$ apart.